# PPTP server remote IP assignment causing problems

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp, pptpd

Our PPTP vpn server (Ubuntu) is working as it's supposed to, but because of the way it assigns remote IP addresses it's causing some problems with our other software.

Example: machine A joins the VPN and is assigned the address 172.16.0.100, and then connects to our program which identifies hosts based on their IP address on the VPN. To improve performance, our program maintains a cache of the socket connections. Then let's say machine A leaves the VPN right before machine B joins, so that machine B is given the now-free 172.16.0.100 address. Since our program maintains the socket connection cache, it now sees machine B as machine A, since A was the last machine with the 172.16.0.100 address!

Having explained all of that, I'd like to clarify that I'm only looking for fixes that would involve configuration of the VPN server/clients. I realize I'm not giving very much information to work with, but I'd really rather not say too much about the infrastructure of our network (company secrets and all that :)

Basically, all I'd like to know is whether or not it would be possible to change the way the server assigns remote IP addresses; i.e., assigning them in ascending order, etc. I've briefly glanced at the pptpd source code, and it seems like there's a possible solution in making changes at the source level, but I wanted to see if anybody had done this in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

> because of the way it assigns remote IP addresses it's causing some
>   problems with our other software

I'd say it's the software that's at fault. You can't blame the VPN because the software is wonky. The VPN is, in fact, working correctly.

That being said, does the VPN server allow the client to specifiy its' ip address? If so, then you could configure each VPN client to use a specific ip address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the VPN server can allow the client to specify it's IP address, the problem with that is we are distributing the client program to our (human) clients, of which the number will constantly be changing, and thus we can't just set those IP addresses by hand.
I suppose we could have some sort of code that increments the IP address the client uses after each download or something...